# Out of universe - Was the Y-wing design influenced by The Enterprise?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, spaceship, inspiration, uss-enterprise

I find the Y-wing has a quite unique design among the star wars crafts and always wondered if it was influenced from elsewhere.

Despite the difference in sheer size it looks similar to the Enterprise for me.  Both have a "saucer" section housing crew and weaponry, they have a "body" containing engines and they are also propelled by rather large "gondolas".  This is quite in contrast to the other star wars craft which seem to have a large main body housing crew, weapons engines and propulsion.

So are there any references about its origin?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly it was; http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/29-Assault-400x198.png and http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/30-Assault_inverted-400x196.png

Comment: not sure if Richard's comment is ironic or not. I wouldn't equate the Y-wing cockpit w/ a saucer, nor is the body of the Y-Wing offset like the engineering sections of the Enterprise but rather is all on the same plane as it were. I suppose the main point of comparison is the nacelle like feature on the Y-Wing? http://www.coldnorth.com/owen/game/miscellaney/comparisons/compare.htm

Comment: I think it might well have been, but mainly they wanted a Y to go with their X.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Probably not

The Y-Wing was based on a design by Star Wars production modeller **Colin Cantwell** that was updated by **Joe Johnston** before reaching production.  It was also influenced by **Ralph McQuarrie**, who made pantings of designs as they were conceived.

None of these individuals have referenced Star Trek or the Enterprise when discussing the Y-Wing.  Also, similarities to the Enterprise seem to be in the eye of the beholder.  My eyes do not see a "saucer section" in the Y-Wing:

[image]

You can read about McQuarrie's influence on various Star Wars designs at the [official Star Wars web site](http://www.starwars.com/news/an-annotated-guide-to-the-star-wars-portfolio-by-ralph-mcquarrie) — I used this article to confirm the parties involved in the Y-Wing's creation.

Comment: Agreed. There's always going to be unintended "similarity" to another work, and thus someone somewhere will try to correlate the two, even though they have absolutely nothing to do with the other (outside of being the same genre).